# Vaadin: Highlight empty components with error message on submitting

Tags: java, validation, vaadin, styling, error-messaging

I have a question on how does the vaadin framework work with `setRequired(true)`. What I found is when user focuses the component field and then exiting it, the error message appears. Here are the fields that are in my `Dialog`.

```
    private final TextField nameField = new TextField("Expense Name");
    private final TextArea descriptionField = new TextArea("Description");
    private final NumberField amountField = new NumberField("Amount");
    private final ComboBox<String> intervalField = new ComboBox<>("Interval");
    private final ComboBox<String> categoryField = new ComboBox<>("Category");
    private final DatePicker dateField = new DatePicker("Date");

    private final Component[] requiredComponents = {nameField, amountField, categoryField, intervalField};

    //...

    private List<Component> getListOfEmptyComponents() {
        return Arrays.stream(requiredComponents)
                .filter(component -> component instanceof HasValue<?, ?> && ((HasValue<?, ?>) component).isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private void setupRequiredComponents() {
        Arrays.stream(requiredComponents).forEach(c -> {
            ((HasValue<?, ?>) c).setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
            ((HasValidationProperties) c).setErrorMessage("Please fill this field");
        });
    }
```

I want, after the user presses the "Save" button, all the empty required fields to be like the screenshot below.

[image]

These error messages are gain after I click (focus) the field and left it, and the components have the `setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);`, but I want them to be visible after user clicks on Save button. Is this possible without me adding my own error messages and styling them ? Any help will be great!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually adding required and other validations to your fields, it's recommended to use the `Binder`.

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder

Once the user pressed save and you check whether or not the form is valid. The validate method of the binder also displays all fields as invalid, like shown in your requirement once you let it validate the form on save.

Comment: This question is not about the saving and validation process on a component, but more on highlighting the required components, so it will be easier for user to understand what fields he should fill.

Comment: The answer still stands. Call Binder::validate. This can also be done while you init the form and highlight all fields / mark them as required.